Debian 12.5: install default-libmysqlclient-dev and default-libmysqlclient-dev:arm64 at the same time
I'm trying to setup a multi-platform build environment for amd64 and arm64.
It is based on debian 12 (amd64). I install all requored amd64 packages
and then I install the reqired packages for arm64 support
dpkg --add-architecture arm64
apt update
apt install g++-11-aarch64-linux-gnu libssl-dev:arm64 libcurl4-openssl-dev:arm64 liblzma-dev:arm64

I install libssl-dev:arm64 libcurl4-openssl-dev:arm64 liblzma-dev:arm64 , because the sources that I will build, depend on them.
Everything is correct until now - libssl-dev:arm64 libcurl4-openssl-dev:arm64 liblzma-dev:arm64 have both the amd64 version and the arm64 version, so that I can compile both for amd64 and arm64 against them.
ii  libssl3:amd64                       3.0.13-1~deb12u1               amd64        Secure Sockets Layer toolkit - shared libraries
ii  libssl3:arm64                       3.0.13-1~deb12u1               arm64        Secure Sockets Layer toolkit - shared libraries

The problem comes when trying to install default-libmysqlclient-dev:arm64
apt install default-libmysqlclient-dev:arm64
The following packages will be REMOVED:
  default-libmysqlclient-dev libmariadb-dev libmariadb-dev-compat

The installation of default-libmysqlclient-dev:arm64 is trying to remove default-libmysqlclient-dev
After that, if I try to install default-libmysqlclient-dev:
apt install default-libmysqlclient-dev
The following packages will be REMOVED:
  default-libmysqlclient-dev:arm64 libmariadb-dev:arm64 libmariadb-dev-compat:arm64

If I try to install both default-libmysqlclient-dev and default-libmysqlclient-dev:arm64:
apt install default-libmysqlclient-dev default-libmysqlclient-dev:arm64
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 default-libmysqlclient-dev:arm64 : Depends: libmariadb-dev-compat:arm64 but it is not installable

If I try to install both libmariadb-dev libmariadb-dev:arm64 (actually, these are the base packages that are required)
apt install libmariadb-dev libmariadb-dev:arm64
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
  libmariadb-dev : Conflicts: libmariadb-dev:arm64 but 1:10.11.6-0+deb12u1 is to be installed
  libmariadb-dev:arm64 : Conflicts: libmariadb-dev but 1:10.11.6-0+deb12u1 is to be installed

It looks like the amd64 and arm64 versions of mariadb cannot exist at the same time. This defeats the idea of crosscompilation.
There is no issue with the other packages to have different architectures at the same time.
Is there an easy solution? Other than manually copying arm64 headers and libraries for mariadb in corresponding system directories.
